# Unable to cast object from viewstate to collection

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, collections, viewstate

I'm storing a collection of `List<KeyValuePair<string, bool>>`
in ViewState, the problem occurs when i'm trying to cast it back to `List<KeyValuePair<string, bool>>`
Error states

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Boolean]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[System.String,System.Boolean]]'.

So how can convert my key value list back from the ViewState ?

My code line is:

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, bool>> myObject = (List<KeyValuePair<string, bool>>)ViewState["listOutputWords"];
```

Comment: please paste your code what you have tried??

Comment: List<KeyValuePair<string, bool>> myObject = (List<KeyValuePair<string, bool>>)ViewState["listOutputWords"];

Comment: And what you put in `ViewState["listOutputWords"]`? Also show full exception data.

Comment: I've added the full exception

Comment: i think you are saving `KeyValuePair<string, bool>` in `ViewState["listOutputWords"]`

Comment: You right!, i was saving dictionary by mistake Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:-

```
KeyValuePair<string, bool> myObject = (KeyValuePair<string, bool>)ViewState["listOutputWords"];
```

As clearly mentioned by the compiler, your ViewState is holding a generic `Dictionary` of `String,Bool` but you are trying to cast it to List of Dictionary which is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the exception, you're saving a `Dictionary<string, bool>` in `ViewState`. If you really need a `List<KeyValuePair<string, bool>>`, try:

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, bool>> myObject = ((Dictionary<string, bool>)ViewState["listOutputWords"]).ToList();
```

Or you could just deserialize it to a dictionary and use that:

```
Dictionary<string, bool> myObject = (Dictionary<string, bool>)ViewState["listOutputWords"];
```